# Exponential decay of Fisher information along the OU semigroup

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, jensen-inequality, fisher-information

I read from a paper that there is a "well-known" exponential decay of Fisher information along the OU semigroup, that is $$J(\nu^t\mid\gamma)\leq e^{-2t}J(\nu\mid\gamma),$$

where $\gamma$ is the standard gaussian distribution and $\nu\ll\gamma$ is any probability measure with density $h$, and $d\nu^t=P_thd\gamma$ where $P_t$ is the OU semigroup corresponding to the SDE $dX_t=-X_tdt+\sqrt{2}dW_t$.

I found [this blog](https://djalil.chafai.net/blog/2016/02/13/aspects-of-the-ornstein-uhlenbeck-process/) as a reference for the proof(I appreciate it if you can direct me to another source!) which is as in the screenshot below.

[image: Proof from the blog]

And I got stuck on the red-step: how is that a Jensen's inequality? What is the convex function here? What I have so far is that if we view the numerator as a constant(for fixed x), and apply Jensen's inequality with $1/x$, then we get something like $$\frac{P_t|\nabla h|^2}{P_th}\leq P_t|\nabla h|^2P_t\frac{1}{h},$$ which is still different from what we want: $P_t\frac{|\nabla h|^2}{h}$.

Comment: Just noticed a notation problem: in the screenshot $\mu_t$ is my $\nu^t$ above, and resp. $\mu_0$ is my $\nu$. In the post, $\gamma_n$ is the standard gaussian in $n$-dimension, I just ignored this subscript.

Comment: Just realized for the original question one single Cauchy-Schwarz is enough instead of two Jensen's. I guess the original blog post is just wrong--please point out if it is not.